# Material UI Avatar component sizes not changing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this component

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { Avatar } from "@material-ui/core";

export interface AvatarProps {
  alt?: string;
  src: string;
  variant?: "circle" | "rounded" | "square";
  sizes?: string;
}

const Component: FC<AvatarProps> = (props: AvatarProps): JSX.Element => {
  return <Avatar {...props}></Avatar>;
};

export default Component;
```

I am trying to set the sizes property but it is not changing. What exactly does it take value?

Answer (score 15):

### MUI 5

Using the `sx` prop provided by the library:

```
<Avatar sx={{ height: '70px', width: '70px' }}></Avatar>
```

...or my preferred method, create a styled component outside your functional component or class. Something like this:

```
const StyledAvatar = ({ children, ...props }) => (
    <Avatar sx={{ height: '70px', width: '70px' }} {...props}>
        {children}
    </Avatar>
);
```

Usage:

```
<StyledAvatar alt="add other props as normal">
    Children can be nested here
</StyledAvatar>;
```

---

### Material UI 4 (Original Answer)

Scroll down to the sizes attribute of img and have a read.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Or just use `makeStyles` as seen in the documentation:

https://v4.mui.com/components/avatars/#SizeAvatars.js

Or another option is a simple inline style:

```
<Avatar style={{ height: '70px', width: '70px' }}></Avatar>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the size with a classname and the theme.spacing from Material UI.

```
 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  sizeAvatar: {
    height: theme.spacing(4),
    width: theme.spacing(4),
  },
}));


...

const classes = useStyles();


<Avatar src="/path/to/image" alt="Avatar" className={classes.sizeAvatar} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting additional Avatar Props

```
<AvatarGroup
 componentsProps={{
       additionalAvatar: {
                 sx: {
                           height: 30,
                             width: 30,
                             background: "red"
                         }
                   }
                  }
               }
         max={2}>
 ....
</AvatarGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately none of the answers worked me.
The only solutions which solved the problem is to use `!important`

I was using the Avatar in a menu.

```
<Avatar
    variant='circular'
    alt={currentUser.firstName}
    src={currentUser.photoUrl}
    sx={{
        width: '80px !important', height: '80px !important'
}} />
```